# Display only last 2 months in amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to display only last 2 months data in amcharts. If user want previous data then he should scroll..

How can i do that?
Display only last 2 months in amcharts. See image. So i want data of only Nov, Oct and Sep or half september, Not till March. Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zoom to the point you want to start show the data to the last data item. Please check the code below:

```
// Add the event listener
chart.addListener("init", zoomChart);

function zoomChart(e) {
  var chart = e.chart;
  var dataProvider = chart.dataProvider;

  // Zoom to the last 60 data items
  e.chart.zoomToIndexes(dataProvider.length - 60, dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

Please check the example below. It uses a different approach where it shows the first day of the previous month.

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/820eb490acae7b3a9f1346fc2144e27a?editors=1010